# Error in Magento 2.1.5 Component Install

Tags: magento2, magento2.1.5

I am installing a magento 2 extension for the first time while installing it continuesly saying *Update is already in progress.* I am not sure what is the problem. Magento cron is set properly and readiness check is passed

[image]